# Traducción al español para "Tough love"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

`Tough love` viene a significar tener *mano dura* con los que quieres con el propósito de enseñarles a valerse por sí mismos o a mejorar en algún aspecto.

De [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_love)

> Tough love is an expression used when someone treats another person harshly or sternly with the intent to help them in the long run.
>
> In most uses, there must be some actual love or feeling of affection behind the harsh or stern treatment to be defined as tough love.For example, genuinely concerned parents refusing to support their drug-addicted child financially until he or she enters drug rehabilitation would be said to be practicing tough love.

Aunque yo he usado la expresión "mano dura" en la explicación, alguien puede tener *mano dura* con subordinado o enemigos, o con cualquier otra persona con la que no hay ese sentimiento afectivo (cierto que incluso esa definición de wikipedia deja entrever que hay una barrera difusa entre la intención y el sentimiento en cuanto a aplicar este término).

Hay alguna traducción en español mejor que "mano dura" para `tough love`? Algo que deje entrever menor que alguien puede ser estricto con alguien a quien quiere con la intención de beneficiar a esa persona?

Comment: En España tenemos el refrán *quien bien te quiere te hará llorar*, que expresa la misma idea. En algunos casos podríamos jugar con este refrán, que es suficientemente conocido como para que se entienda una referencia a él.

Comment: Antes de que salieran a la luz tantos casos lamentables de violencia de género, el dicho "porque te quiero te aporreo" tenía el sentido más inocente de que uno sólo es duro o exigente con aquél a quien ama (*tough love*). No obstante, hoy en día ese dicho puede ser mal visto como una justificación de la violencia contra las mujeres. De todos modos, yo lo sigo oyendo en el buen sentido de la expresión y, a pesar de la connotación negativa que ahora se le atribuye, lo usaría para referirme al concepto citado por Diego.

Comment: En casa tenemos un libro titulado [Cómo educar con firmeza y cariño](https://www.amazon.es/EDUCAR-FIRMEZA-CARI%C3%91O-NI%C3%91OS-ADOLESCENTES/dp/8497990331/ref=sr_1_1), basado en la disciplina positiva. La parte de "firmeza y cariño" no sé si podría ser un equivalente (que no traducción) para lo del "tough love".

Answer (score 5):

La expresión que buscas es **"amor severo"**.

> **[severo, ra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XkW4kQj)**
>   Del lat. *sevērus*.
>   1. adj. Riguroso, áspero, duro en el trato o el castigo.
>   2. adj. Exacto y rígido en la observancia de una ley, un precepto o una regla.

No puedo poner ahora fuentes exactas, pero [si buscas en Google](https://www.google.es/search?q=%22amor%20severo%22) podrás ver que se refiere exactamente al concepto que indicas. Por ejemplo, [en Linguee](http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/traduccion/amor+severo.html) se traduce siempre como *tough love*.
Es una expresión que [ya usaba Cervantes](https://books.google.es/books?id=gnGZg53sCoAC&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=%22amor%20severo%22&source=bl&ots=XrDqgy75Lk&sig=oWT9wDdEtFeaXfGbg1_gM2_TXFU&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM4e-9qIPWAhWJh7QKHZVkBgE4ChDoAQhDMAg#v=onepage&q=%22amor%20severo%22&f=false), con lo que su hispanidad está fuera de toda duda.

Comment: Interesante, no creo haber oído nunca *amor severo* pero es mucho mejor que *mano dura* que no tiene esa connotación de afecto y puede ser simple brutalidad.

Answer (score 2):

**Educar con amor duro**

La verdad es que aunque la traducción correcta sea "amor duro" lo más probable es que cuando la uses necesites un contexto, no como en inglés. Creo que sería mejor utilizar "Educar con amor duro". Esta expresión si indica lo que "Tough Love" significa aunque requiere una palabra extra en español.

He encontrado algunas referencias:

> Libro: *El secreto del niño feliz: Una guía imprescindible para padres
>   y educadores*
>
> (...) "El movimiento de 'Tough Love' ("Amor Duro") en los EE.UU.
>   parece muy práctico para los padres que tienen problemas con sus
>   hijos" (...)
>   [link al libro en google books](https://books.google.es/books?id=w83OYQeWS8AC&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=educar%20con%20amor%20duro&source=bl&ots=9IhQlBgyln&sig=2ygKhwx5feVGX_vRGD-Jy0L5NUo&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBiO3-44PWAhVCWRoKHVHDCiwQ6AEIXTAN#v=onepage&q=educar%20con%20amor%20duro&f=false)